# How to make a function retain its variable value on every recursive call?

Tags: python

I have function `find_schema_differences(a, b)`, which compares two nested dictionaries and returns the difference.

```
def find_schema_differences(master_schema, client_schema):
    differences = []
    for x in master_schema:
        if type(master_schema[x]) is not dict:
            if not x in client_schema or master_schema[x] != client_schema[x]:
                differences.append({x: master_schema[x]})
        else:
            if x not in client_schema or not find_schema_differences(
                master_schema[x], client_schema[x]
            ):
                differences.append({x: master_schema[x]})
    return differences
```

But this resets the 'differences' variable to empty list on every iteration.

I tried this the following but it doesn't look good:

```
def find_schema_differences(master_schema, client_schema):
    differences = []
    def find_difference(master_schema, client_schema):
        for x in master_schema:
            if type(master_schema[x]) is not dict:
                if not x in client_schema or master_schema[x] != client_schema[x]:
                    differences.append({x: master_schema[x]})
            else:
                if x not in client_schema or not find_difference(
                    master_schema[x], client_schema[x]
                ):
                    differences.append({x: master_schema[x]})
        return differences
    find_difference(master_schema, client_schema)
    return differences
```

So, is there a way I can improve on this?

Comment: You probably want to append whatever recursive call returns to the list before returning it.

Comment: The inner function is fine, but I don't think your `not find_difference(...)` will do what you like now, because `differences` will have contents from the earlier iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd reformulate this as a recursive generator function:

```
def find_schema_differences(master_schema, client_schema):
    for master_key, master_value in master_schema.items():
        if master_key not in client_schema:
            yield (master_key, master_value)
        elif not isinstance(master_value, dict):
            if client_schema[master_key] != master_value:
                yield (master_key, master_value)
        else:
            found_deep_difference = False
            for diff in find_schema_differences(master_value, client_schema[master_key]):
                found_deep_difference = True
                yield diff
            if found_deep_difference:
                yield (master_key, master_value)
```

The `found_deep_difference` logic may not be what you expect; please adjust according to your requirements...

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the list of differences to the function itself:

```
def find_schema_differences(master_schema, client_schema, differences=[]):
        for x in master_schema:
            if type(master_schema[x]) is not dict:
                if not x in client_schema or master_schema[x] != client_schema[x]:
                    differences.append({x: master_schema[x]})
            else:
                if x not in client_schema or not find_schema_differences(
                    master_schema[x], client_schema[x]
                ):
                    differences.append({x: master_schema[x]})
        return differences


differences = []    
differences = find_schema_differences(master_schema, client_schema, differences=differences)
```

Like this, your differences would always append to the differences list. This avoids making this list a global variable, which would also be possible, but is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you were after:

```
def find_schema_differences(d1, d2):
    return dict(
        (k, v) if not isinstance(d1[k], dict) else (k, find_schema_differences(d1[k], d2[k]))
        for k, v in d1.items() if k not in d2 or d1[k] != d2[k]
    )


a = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': {'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}}
b = {'x': 1, 'y': 3, 'z': {'a': 1, 'b': 3}}
differences = find_schema_differences(a, b)

print(differences)
```

Result:

```
{'y': 2, 'z': {'b': 2, 'c': 3}}
```

As for the answer to your question, what you did is not a bad way to create a variable that remains accessible over several calls, although you should generally consider returning the local result and constructing the overall result from the returned values in a recursive solution.

You indicated in comments that you found the compact Python syntax hard to read - I don't blame you, it takes some getting used to. This code does the same, and I assume you might find it a bit easier on the eyes, though it may not perform as well:

```
def find_schema_differences(d1, d2):
    result = {}
    for k, v in d1.items():
        if k not in d2 or d1[k] != d2[k]:
            if not isinstance(d1[k], dict):
                result[k] = v
            else:
                result[k] = find_schema_differences(d1[k], d2[k])
    return result
```

Comment: This definitely works but, i find it hard to read.

Comment: That's a fair comment - that format is something you get used to, coding Python, but I've added an alternative that's almost as fast and probably more readable in your opinion. Of course you could just rename `d1` and `d2` as well, but I picked short names to keep things a bit more compact for the example here.